# Latex for notes search offline?

Tags: search, research

I want to build my own notes framework, but except refer to the GitHub pages(website way), I want to use latex files offline.

But compared with online notes, I don't know how can I search keywords in different latex files compared with the website that offers the search function which is the most thing I want for my notes.  So is there some way that I can search the keywords in different latex files offline?

Comment: that is a question about your operating system not tex, linux and similar systems have the `grep` utility, or windows you can use the standard searchbox in the toolbar or in the filemanager or your editor may provide multi-file search or ...

Comment: Beside to use grep, to take notes consider use Zim (also for Windows). It  is a graphical wiki editor of  notebooks. The drawback is that wiki format is limited, is not LaTeX, and not designed to produce a PDF directly, but single pages or the whole notebook can be exported easily from Zim to very clean LaTeX files (or some other formats). The advantage regarding your problem is that beside organize topics  is a hierarchical tree structure, you can mark pages with add labels, search words, in the whole tree or some  branch and use outlines of single pages to quicly find any subject.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I mean, can I search the content inside the single latex? Not the name of the latex fil.

Comment: latex files are simply text files, you can use any search tool that you have, as I say grep will be available in linux (and can be installed for windows) but there are many alternatives.  there is nothing latex specific in your question. For example if I want to know all the tex files I have in a directory using `fontspec` then `grep -l fontspec *tex` will return that list.